# How do i convert text data to jpeg format image?

Tags: php, image

I am a newbie in php so please spare me for my mistakes.

I download a image file from a website too use it with ocr but when i download the image file from the site i get a php file of which i have to first change extension to .jpeg and then convert using it a image converter to use it with ocr. I wanted to know is there a way i could convert it using php to jpeg format to use it with the ocr. I tried few methods listed in other question and their answers but they are not working, they return an unreadable which i cant even view in windows.

**Here is the sample image :** http://www.datafilehost.com/d/2bc5fcd5

**Here is the sample image converted by php :** http://www.datafilehost.com/d/a1c902fb

This is the code i used to convert the php file to image:

```
global $buf;

$imagepath = 'securimage_show.php';
$imagedata = GetFileData($imagepath);

ob_start();
$length = strlen($imagedata);
header('Last-Modified: '.date('r'));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: '.$length);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
print($imagedata);
ob_end_flush();
/*======FUNCTIONS USED======*/
function GetFileData($imagepath){
    $fp = fopen($imagepath, 'rb') or die('404! Unable to open file!');
    $buf = '';
    while(!feof($fp)){
        $buf .= fgets($fp, 4096);
    }
    fclose($fp);
return $buf; //returns False if failed, else the contents up to FileSize bytes.
}
    $imag = imagejpeg($buf);
    file_put_contents("qeqxcxew.jpg", $imag);
```

I can view the image in the browser when the code outputs it in the browser so i assume that i am making mistake in saving the file. Please help

Thanks

Akash

Comment: ensure the directory this script is in (the same one your script is saving the file to) is writable. Also, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the script to see if there are any errors.

Comment: i tried that i got no error, and i opened the image in a notepad++ and i found that it was empty there was no data inside it

Comment: try `file_put_contents("qeqxcxew.jpg", $buf);`

Comment: i have alredy tried that it gives a corrupt image